# apt-get broken after partial update to 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, apt

I updated my Dell OEM linux machine from 14.04 to 16.04. Something went wrong during the upgrade and when I tried to login it got stuck in a loop I managed to fix it using the tty terminal and manually connect to wifi using wpa_supplicant. My apt-get is now stuck with `33 not fully installed or removed.` when I run `apt-get autoremove` or `apt-get install -f` i get the same errors. It quits with this error message.

```
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 ufw
 gufw
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-generic-lts-xenial
 linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-92-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic
 initramfs-tools
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is the full output of `sudo apt-get autoremove` 
https://pastebin.com/18zbyBAK

Comment: First error seems to be `mv: '/lib/ufw/user.rules' and '/etc/ufw/user.rules' are the same file`. You could try renaming/moving one of them and see if that helps? At least it should give you one less error.

Comment: It looks like `initramfs` is failing.  What happens if you do `sudo initramfs -u -k all -v`?

Comment: @NateEldredge I get `sudo: initramfs: command not found` or without sudo `initramfs: command not found`

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all -v`

Comment: First, your machine seems to still be running + rebooting may fail, so if you haven't take a full backup, best to this now. Whenever I hit this type of problem in a update, I tend to just delete the offending package, so in your case delete ufw + any other package in error. The try + do a repair. Usually dpkg --configure -a is sufficient... well... after all packages that can't be recovered are removed.

Comment: @NateEldredge with that I get `update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic with 1.`

Comment: That's the only output?  Nothing else?

Comment: @NateEldredge here is the entire output https://pastebin.com/GQwFNgWi

Comment: I sit worth just reinstalling ubuntu?

Comment: @Baasic: At this point yes, I would consider reinstalling.  It's probably fixable somehow, but at best there would be a long slow process of going back and forth with experts, trying to figure out what information is needed to diagnose the problem and passing it back and forth.  Reinstalling will probably get you a working system more quickly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up copying off my home data and reinstalling 16.04

Comment: This is YOUR solution, which did NOT actually solved the problem, it should be unmarked as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I solved it with:

```
sudo mv /etc/ufw/user{,6}.rules /lib/ufw/
```

It seems the installation script awaits real files in `/lib/ufw/user{,6}.rules` and want to copy them to `/etc/ufw/user{,6}.rules` AND then create a link from the old location to the new, probably for compatibility reasons. However, the script doesn't check if it already set up this way.

The given instruction (first instruction on the top) is simply erasing the links and move the 2 files back to `/lib/ufw` where it seems that `ufw` install script is expecting them.

Afterwards, `sudo apt-get install -f` went through `ufw` installation process without complaining.

Answer (score -1):

Controll with `df -h;df -i` if you have enough space particulary if a seperate boot-partition is present.

In the case boot-partition is full `dpkg -l 'linux-[ihs]*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([-0-9]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo dpkg -P` This removes every kernel-package besides your current running Kernel.

Not this case?

```
sudo dpkg -P ufw gufw linux-generic-lts-xenial  linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic
```

Install initramfs-tools directly with dpkg. `sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/initramfs-tools-full-packagename.deb` Use autocomplete. We need it.

In both cases `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install` If apt is free please run `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`

Good luck.

Comment: There is no .deb file for initramfs-tools in `/archive`

Comment: Bad `wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools_0.122ubuntu8.9_all.deb`  After that package is in your curent pwd.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 for that url: 
`--2017-11-24 00:17:03--  http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B/initramfs-tools_0.1%E2%80%8C22ubuntu8.9_all.deb
Reusing existing connection to mirrors.kernel.org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-11-24 00:17:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Comment: Great. `wget -c http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-tools/initramfs-tools_0.122ubuntu8.9_all.deb` This is working.  I try it.

Comment: same 404 

`--2017-11-24 11:07:52--  http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/initramfs-to%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bols/initramfs-tools_%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B0.122ubuntu8.9_all.d%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Beb
Reusing existing connection to de.archive.ubuntu.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-11-24 11:07:53 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Comment: Never mind I got it. it was the formatting of your `_` and `.` that was trowing it off.